# How can we access non static protected method in main{as we cannot access protected members by creating objects} for java?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
package foo;
public  class scj{

protected  void disp()
{
System.out.println("package");
}

} 
*********************

import foo.scj;
public class aq extends scj{
public static void main(String args[])
{disp();
}
}
```

If disp is static , then program runs perfectly fine. But for non static it gives error that-non static members cant be referenced from static method.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Make the member static, or
2. Make the method non-static, or
3. Pass the non-static state into your static method via a parameter.

Comment: Elaborate on how exactly can we use (3.)point.

Comment: #3 is here for completeness; I don't think it applies to your specific situation, because there's nothing to pass.  In this naive case,  I would simply make the "member" (in this case, your function `disp`) static.